# Insert data in one table within multiple app at the same time with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have written `eight source code` to insert some value to a database called "TA" in one table called "8box". I am planning to run this `eight source code` at the same time,and then this `eight source code` keeps storing data in database in almost  one hour. I wrote this code for collecting data, and each of this `eight source code` have the same syntax to insert values to "8box"

I want to run this `eight source code` at the same time to be able to collect data.

I tried this and the result is that the database is just filled with values from first source code, none values from another source stored in database

What should i do ?

```
waktu=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'qwer1234', 'TA');
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    #cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 8Box")
    #cur.execute("CREATE TABLE 8Box (Name VARCHAR(25),Lot_Bid INT,Bid INT,Offer INT,Lot_Offer INT,Time DATETIME)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_1_new,bid_1_new,off_1_new,lot_off_1_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_2_new,bid_2_new,off_2_new,lot_off_2_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_3_new,bid_3_new,off_3_new,lot_off_3_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_4_new,bid_4_new,off_4_new,lot_off_4_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_5_new,bid_5_new,off_5_new,lot_off_5_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_6_new,bid_6_new,off_6_new,lot_off_6_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_7_new,bid_7_new,off_7_new,lot_off_7_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_8_new,bid_8_new,off_8_new,lot_off_8_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_9_new,bid_9_new,off_9_new,lot_off_9_new,waktu))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name_new,lot_bid_10_new,bid_10_new,off_10_new,lot_off_10_new,waktu))
```

Comment: commit your transaction so you release the lock?

Comment: whats is the lock for ?

Comment: mysql locks the section of the disk that you're writing to and without committing (calling the commit method on the connection object), the database will most likely remain locked for any other writers to that table. (this would be easier to show if you gave us some code...)

Comment: i done adding code to my post

Comment: that code is from first source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `MySQLdb` interface and not the `_mysql` interface. I would code it as:

```
cn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
c = cn.cursor()
try:
    c.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO 8Box VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
    """,  [
        (name_new,lot_bid_1_new,bid_1_new,off_1_new,lot_off_1_new,waktu),
        (name_new,lot_bid_2_new,bid_2_new,off_2_new,lot_off_2_new,waktu),
        # .. etc.
        (name_new,lot_bid_10_new,bid_10_new,off_10_new,lot_off_10_new,waktu)
    ])
    cn.commit()
except:
    cn.rollback()
    raise
```

**Update:** here's a screendump of the two processes running simultaneously:

[image]

Comment: i try this code, the result is same as before, its just store the values from first source code

Comment: How do you discover (which  tool do you use) that only the values from the first process i getting in the database? Have you verified  that the other code is actually running (is it hanging on the execute? are you committing there too?)

Comment: i know it by looking directly in to database, and the values from first source code in there, i dont know how to verified the other code is running or not, but i (type python file1.py && python file2.py) just example to run the source code, and i committing in another code

Comment: You could put e.g. `print "this is file2 running"` inside file2.py to see if it's running (and when). In this case it is because the `&&` doesn't do what you think it does (it waits for the left-hand process to finish, and if it finishes with an exit code of `0`, then it starts the right-hand process..)

Comment: oke, now i already know the 2nd code is running cause of, i save temporary values in to file2.txt , it just the 2nd code skipped inserting data in to database, but the values saved in file2,txt is true,

Comment: i write the 2nd code same as the first code, in inserting database session i mean, and i already using ur code sample

how about i made a service for this ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing that two processes doing inserts in the described manner will both insert into the database. If you're still having problems it might be for some other reason...?